# Navigation submenu - appear to left

Tags: html, css

I successfully got an appear-to-right submenu method working after posting this: [Navigation submenu creates white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049180/navigation-submenu-creates-white-space/53049288#53049288)

My problem now is that I want the submenus on the right most side of the screen to appear to the left of the initial dropdown menu. I thought I'd be able to use the same code I have to make them appear to the right by adding a `position: relative; left: -350px` or something to make it appear to the left. But that actually created the same white space issue I had before.

There is probably an easy solution to this, but I sure can't figure it out.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
right: 180px;
}

.dropdown2 {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdownsub {
  position: absolute;
  display: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  min-width: 180px;
}

.dropdown-subcontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  min-width: 180px;
  background: orange;
}

@media (max-width: 1086px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-subcontent {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownsub:hover .dropdown-subcontent {
  display: none;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Accounts Receivable</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body bgcolor="#cccccc">
  <div class='dropdown'>
    <button class='dropbtn'>MENU<i class='fas fa-chevron-down'></i></button>
    <div class='dropdown-content'>
      <a href='#'>Option 1</a>
      <div class='dropdown2'>
        <a href='#'>Submenu ></a>
        <div class='dropdown-subcontent'>
          <a href='#'>Submenu Option 1</a>
          <a href='#'>Submenu Option 2</a>
          <a href='#'>Submenu Option 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href='#'>Option 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.dropdown-subcontent {
right:100%;
}
```

Do this instead of left:100%;